# The best way to browse rubygems documents on console

Tags: ruby

It is easy to find rubygems documents on the Web, but I want to read them on my console.

`ri` is not enough for me, because I have to know the name of class or method before reading ri. At that time, however, I don't know anything other than the package name!

So I need the fastest way to find synopsys of rubygems, something like perldoc.

Is there any good way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bundler you can always do:

```
$ bundle open gemname
```

which will open the gem in your `$EDITOR` allowing you to check out the `README.rdoc` (or whatever the author is using as root documentation) not to mention all of the source code. Very helpful when debugging too!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried typing `ri` at the command line and pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> then, at the prompt, entered the first letters of something you're curious about, pressed <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice, and let it show you the matches? Or, put in a single letter and press <kbd>Return</kbd> and let ri show you what starts with that letter? Or, from the command-line, simply typed `ri -l`?

Or, have you tried typing `gem server` at the command-line, then opened a browser window to `http://0.0.0.0:8808` to see the documentation for the gems installed in your current Ruby?